# Search Dexie Table column for a list of keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, dexie

I have a list of keys like this

```
keys:string[] = [3290, 43827, 5894, 3747]
```

these keys are unique and they sit in the column 'scheme_codes' of table 'schemes' in IndexDB

I'm using Dexie to query my database
I know how to search for a key in a specified column like this

```
this.table('schemes').where('scheme_codes').equals(3290)
```

But I couldn't find any resource to search for a list of keys

I have tried this.table.bulkGet([...]), it works but it searches for the key in all of the columns, which is something, I can't gamble with

I could really use your help & Thanks for spending your time for my question

Comment: How is your schema defined (db.version(x).stores(...))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050422/write-multiple-where-condition-using-dexie-js), you can do something like:

```
this.table('schemes').where('scheme_codes').anyOf([3290, 43827, 5894, 3747])
```